# Not going to my error message when I submitting the form

Tags: php

I use this code to validate select box value. But my problem is when I submit form without selecting an option in select box its not going to error message.

```
if ( !isset( $_POST['how_hear'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Select an option from How did you hear us select box';                             
} else {
    $howHear = $_POST['how_hear'];
}
```

this is my select box

```
$howHear = array( 1 =>  'option value 01', 
                                'option value 02', 
                                'option value 03', 
                                'option value 04', 
                                'option value 05', 
                                'option value 06', 
                                'option value 07', 
                                'option value 08'
                        );

echo "<select name='how_hear'>
        <option>--Select an Option--</option>\n";

    foreach ( $howHear AS $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value='{$key}'";

        // Check for stickyness:
        if ( $_POST['how_hear'] == $key){
            echo " selected='selected'";
        }
        echo ">$value</option>\n";
    }
echo "</select>\n";
```

Can anybody tell my where I have gone wrongly? 
Thank you.

Comment: what you getting in `die($_POST['how_hear'])` when you submit without selecting select box ?

Comment: where  I need to put this debugging code. I tried it with placing into my validation code. but it not display anything.

Comment: you can put this before `if ( !isset( $_POST['how_hear'])) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that how_hear is set. The default is

```
--Select an Option--
```

Check that

```
$_POST['how_hear'] != "--Select an Option--"
```

Alternatively, update your select field so that the default value is 0 (this would be the correct thing to do). And then check that the value is non-zero.

```
<option value="0">--Select an Option--</option>
```

Comment: I tried it something like this.. if ( !isset( $_POST['how_hear']) && $_POST['how_hear'] != "--Select an Option--" ) {

Comment: Change the && to an ||. The way you have it, you're saying "If how_hear is not set, and it equals something". This logically makes no sense. However, you're better off setting the option value to 0 and testing as follows: if(!isset($_POST['how_hear']) || $_POST['how_hear'] == 0) { . . . }

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<option value="0">--Select an Option--</option>
```

and

```
if (  $_POST['how_hear'] == 0) {
    //   error message
}
```

Comment: thanks. its working. I have made a mistake in my code I used it like $_POST['how_hear'] == '0'

Comment: @TharangaNuwan  "0" i string and 0 is int .. yours very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add another condition with this,

```
if ( !isset( $_POST['how_hear']) || $_POST['how_hear'] == "") {
    $errors[] = 'Select an option from How did you hear us select box';                             
} else {
    $howHear = $_POST['how_hear'];
}
```

Comment: I don't think $_POST['how_hear'] will ever equate to "". If i'm not mistaken, it will have the text between the option tags.

Answer (score 0):

I made some change in your code and update.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
       if ($_POST['how_hear'] == 0)
       {
           echo "error";
           $errors[] = 'Select an option from How did you hear us select box';                             
       }    
       else 
       {
           echo "Hello";
           $howHear = $_POST['how_hear'];
       }
     }

    echo "<form method='post' action='#'>";
    $howHear = array( 1 =>  'option value 01', 
                            'option value 02', 
                            'option value 03', 
                            'option value 04', 
                            'option value 05', 
                            'option value 06', 
                            'option value 07', 
                            'option value 08'
                    );
    echo "<select name='how_hear'>
        <option>--Select an Option--</option>\n";

        foreach ( $howHear AS $key => $value) 
        {
           echo "<option value='{$key}'>";
           echo "$value</option>\n";
        }

    echo "</select>\n";

    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>";

    echo "</form>";

?>
```

i add submit button and when form is submitted i check submit `isset` or not.
after that i check `how_hear` value selected or not. if option value `0` it will display error.